# Given $ I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n!}e^x\,dx $, prove that $ I_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+I_{n+1} $

Tags: integration, analysis, reduction-formula

$$
I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n!}e^x\,dx
$$

> Prove that
>   $$
> I_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+I_{n+1}
> $$

I tried  integration by parts and still can't prove it, I appreciate any hint/answer.

Comment: Disagree with close vote. OP told us what he tried and asked for a hint.

Comment: Alae: you will get a lot more positive attention to your question if you convert it from a picture to MathJax. See the tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What do you get after integrating by parts?

Comment: I would do this using integration by parts.  Show us your work, and maybe we can see where you went astray.

Comment: For what it is worth: "Montrons que" (with an 'r') means "Let's show that" (indicating that the proof should follow right after). "Prove that" would be "Prouve que" or "Prouvez que".

Answer (score 8):

I used $n!$ as in the original image.$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n!}e^x\,dx=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 \left(-\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)'e^x\,dx$$
$$=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{n!}\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}  e^x\bigg|_0^1}_{=0-\left(-\large\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right)} +\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^xdx $$
$$\Rightarrow I_n=\frac{1}{\color{}{(n+1)!}} +I_{n+1}$$

Comment: The OP already found this result...

Comment: @PeterForeman he wants to prove this from my understanding as he failed by integrating by parts.

Comment: Oh, I thought he wanted the solution to the integral, by combing answers we have both though.

Comment: I took a little bit of french some years ago. Montres means to prove I think.

Comment: Shall I delete my answer then?

Comment: @PeterForeman No, I don't think you should. It provides some valuable info for someone just getting into integration.

Answer (score 5):

Following the proof of the recurrence relation by Zacky, we have
$$I_{n+1}=I_n-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$
$$=I_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$
$$=I_0 - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!}$$
We can calculate $I_0$ as follows
$$I_0 = \int_0^1 e^x dx=[e^x]_0^1=e-1$$
Therefore the final solution is:
$$I_{n+1}=e-1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!}$$
$$=e-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!}$$
or equivalently;
$$I_n=e-\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$$